# Transforming multiclass problem into binary problem to improve accuracy

Tags: multiclass-classification, binary

I found a code for a classifier for a  6 class problem where the classes are integers from 0 to 5.
I found this code that I tested and it improved my accuracy highly.
Can anyone explain the spirit behind the idea of transforming the problem into a binary classification and how it improves the results?

```
class Classifier(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clf1 = BernoulliNB()
        self.clf2 = BernoulliNB()

    def fit(self, X, y):
        y1 = y.copy()
        y1[y==0] = 1; y1[y==2] = 1; y1[y==3] = 4; y1[y==5] = 4
        self.clf1.fit(X, y)
        y2 = y.copy()
        y2[y==1] = 0; y2[y==2] = 0; y2[y==3] = 0; y2[y==4] = 1; y2[y==5] = 1
        self.clf1.fit(X, y1)
        self.clf2.fit(X,y2)

    def predict(self, X):
        self.clf1.predict(X)
        self.clf2.predict(X)

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        A = np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0]])
        proba = self.clf1.predict_proba(X)
        B = self.clf2.predict_proba(X)
        #return proba_modified(np.array(list(map(lambda x: A@x, proba))),B)
        return np.array(list(map(lambda x: A.dot(x), proba)))
```